# how to update the firmware of an epson xp 211 printer in linux?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, printing, firmware

Since the epson utility are available for windows and mac, I was wondering how to update the firmware in Linux.

**Comment>**
Using a virtualized windows/mac machine would work?. I remembered , this was done on an HP inkjet once. The updater was launched, the printer connected via usb, the program recognize the port and device but it get static in some part of the update process, and the version of the firmware was not updated, so the printer simply didn't update.